# Comparing int and int* in C

Tags: c, pointers, integer

I just started C and I'm somewhat confused. As an example:

```
    int *first=0;
    int second=1;
    if(*first<second)
    {
        printf("Works\n");
    }
```

The above example is supposed to give me the print and finish the code.
Instead, it gives me a seg error, but the IDE tell me there are no problems.
In first, aren't I giving the value the pointer is pointing at?
What am I missing here?

Comment: `*first` would indeed be the value of whatever `first` is pointing to – if it pointed to anything.

Comment: "In first, aren't I giving the value the pointer is pointing at?" In your own words, what value do you think that pointer is pointing at? Why do you think it is pointing at any particular value at all? What do you think it means when you write `int *first=0;` - in particular, the `=0` part?

Comment: "I just started C and I'm somewhat confused" If you have fundamental, conceptual difficulties, then you should try to follow a tutorial, or read through a [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/), or get a textbook, or talk with an instructor. Stack Overflow is for solving concrete, specific problems with the code.

Comment: "example is supposed to give me the print and finish the code." is incorrect.  Code is broken at `int *first=0; ... *first`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In general, I didn't understand something fundemental online either so I went to the next best thing. While Stack Overflow is for concrete problems, a lot of students also come here to look for answers, so hey, maybe they misunderstood the lessons like me. Better a specific question online then nothing :)
Also I see now that the example I gave was problomatic due to the ```=0``` part, but It was meant to be generally any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `int *first=0;`, the `0` initializes `first`, not `*first`. That is, it sets the pointer to 0 (making a *null pointer*). A null pointer does not point to any object.

The C standard does not define the behavior of attempting to use a null pointer pointer to access an object, so the behavior of `*first<second` is not defined. A common result is the program attempts to access address zero, and the virtual memory of the process is configured so this causes a hardware exception to be generated, and the program is terminated.

(However, it is also possible that program optimization during compilation may transform an attempt to use a null pointer into other code, causing your program to behave in ways that are mysterious until you become familiar with the effects of optimization.)

To fix this, you need to set `first` to point to a proper object. You can do this by making it point to some other named object, such as:

```
int x;
int *first = &x;
```

or by allocating memory for it:

```
int *first = malloc(sizeof *first);
if (!first)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If you allocate memory, then you usually want to release it later in the program, with `free(first)`, after you are done using it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the rich explanation! Now my code works *and* I understand what I'm doing! I also made sure to make this the correct answer, in case any other newbie gets into the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your code

```c
    int *first=0;
    int second=1;
    if(*first<second)
    {
        printf("Works\n");
    }
```

`first` is a pointer to `int` which points to **address** 0 (that is, a *null pointer*). So, reading memory at address 0 is not allowed as it does not point to any valid object, which produces a [segfault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). So, you need to give the pointer a valid address.

Instead you can try giving the pointer a valid address of a variable which contains the value `0`

Like this ...

```c
    int x = 0;
    int* first = &x;
    int second = 1;
    if(*first < second)
    {
        printf("Works\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With `int *first=0` you are declaring [first] as pointer and initializing the value of **that pointer** to 0. From that point, [first] is pointing to 0-th memory location, which is not at error. However, dereferencing pointer in this stage (reading from memory address = 0) is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
int *first=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));//allocate a pointer of type int
*first=0;//initialize *first with 0
int second=1;
if(*first<second)
{
    printf("Works\n");
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.